# Unity Ad not displaying as i am getting Unity Ads was not able to get current network type due to missing permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, unityads

Here is my initilization of unity ads

```
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
UnityAds.initialize(this, RentC.getApp().GAMEID, null, RentC.getApp().isTestMode, true);
BannerView mBannerView = new BannerView(this, adUnitId, new UnityBannerSize(320, 50));
mAdView.addView(mBannerView);
mBannerView.load();
```

Ads are not displaying and in logcat i am getting

```
2021-08-06 21:54:23.844 25057-25206/com.yrrappz.rent_c W/UnityAds: com.unity3d.services.core.connectivity.ConnectivityMonitor.initConnectionStatus() (line:109) :: Unity Ads was not able to get current network type due to missing permission
2021-08-06 21:54:23.855 25057-25206/com.yrrappz.rent_c I/UnityAds: com.unity3d.services.core.api.Sdk.logInfo() (line:84) :: mediation detection is:{"UnityEngine":false}
2021-08-06 21:54:23.859 25057-25209/com.yrrappz.rent_c W/UnityAds: com.unity3d.services.core.connectivity.ConnectivityMonitor.connectionStatusChanged() (line:173) :: Unity Ads was not able to get current network type due to missing permission
2021-08-06 21:54:23.863 25057-25209/com.yrrappz.rent_c W/UnityAds: com.unity3d.services.core.connectivity.ConnectivityMonitor.connectionStatusChanged() (line:173) :: Unity Ads was not able to get current network type due to missing permission
```

permissions Given

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Can u help me to get out of this

Comment: testmode is true

Comment: The error is quite clear. You are missing a permission in your gradle for your APK.

Comment: Hey, How can solved it?

Answer (score -1):

To expand on my comment, you are missing the required network permission. To enable it follow these steps:

Go to **Edit->Project Settings -> Player**. Select Android, Build Settings, Change Internet Access from **Auto** to **Require**.

If you are using a custom gradle,  you need to add the permission manually. They should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: access networkstat and internat permission already given

Comment: i am unable to find Project Settings

Comment: I have the same error and changing to require doesn't fix the issue. unity 2021 3.0f1. I only have issues on build APK. No issues in play mode